# How to convert the data to the yml file

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a Ruby file, "one.rb":

```
require 'yaml'

e = { "names"=>{"first_name" => "shaik", "last_name" => "farooq"} }

puts e.to_yaml
```

When I run this it gets executed successfully in the console and outputs:

```
---
names:
first_name: shaik
last_name: farooq
```

I want to store the executed data in a file with a "yml" extension. How can I do this from the above file (test.rb)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the yaml to file with:

```
require 'yaml'

e = { "names"=>{"first_name" => "shaik", "last_name" => "farooq"} }

File.open('your_file_name.yml', 'w') { |f| f.write(e.to_yaml) }
```

Comment: when i  run the code in eclipse its show nothing and i cant find the defined yml file.

Comment: Where did you look for the file? You could put a full path in just to see if the code is working at all.

Comment: i mean we need to create the yml file or the file gets created when we run these code, in eclipse i have look for the file but cant find

Comment: This code will create a yml file. The code works if you run it in something like irb (at least with a full path name). Unfortunately, I do not have any experience with eclipse.

Comment: can u please post the screenshot,or any other way i am unable to understand it i tried it on irb console but does nothing ........

Comment: irb(main):005:0> File.open('test.yml', 'w') { |f| f.write(e.to_yaml) }
=> 53     these is the output i got when i executed in irb

Comment: Do a full path for the file then. For example 'c:\folder\name.yml'.

Comment: hey is there any difference between yml and yaml or both of them are same.

Comment: In most cases, it probably does not matter. However, I remember reading at some point that yaml was the official extension. But I am not a heavy yaml user so could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple:

```
require 'yaml'

e = { "names"=>{"first_name" => "shaik", "last_name" => "farooq"} }
File.write('test.yaml', e.to_yaml)
```

After running that, a file called "test.yaml" will exist in the current directory that contains:

```
---
names:
  first_name: shaik
  last_name: farooq
```

You can reload that data easily also:

```
new_e = YAML.load_file('test.yaml')
# => {"names"=>{"first_name"=>"shaik", "last_name"=>"farooq"}}
```